# How to navigate the object graph using JPA Criteria API?

Tags: java, database, jpa-2.0, criteria-api, object-graph

Suppose we have the following class graph:

```
public final class Address {

    private final String streetAddress

    public String getStreetAddress() {
        return streetAddress;
    }

}

public final class House {

    private Address address;
}
```

Now I want to query all the houses that match an specific street address using JPA Criteria API. I tried to do this but it did not work.

```
addPredicate(criteriaBuilder.like(root.<String>get("address.streetAddress"), streetAddress));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by doing:

```
addPredicate(criteriaBuilder.like(root.<Address>get("address").<String>get("streetAddress"), streetAddress));
```